# Outlook rule won't run automatically, works when run manually

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I found many threads in the Microsoft answers community but none of them have worked. This seems to be a common problem for many people that happens for a large number of different reasons. I have methodically and diligently tried every solution suggested.

Running the rule manually proves that the logic is correct. I have a couple other rules that run just fine.

The rule is very simple:

> ```
> Apply this rule after the message arrives
> from email@address.com
> move it to the folder_I_selected folder
> ```

I am currently running in "non-cached" mode. I've removed my old OST files. I've  /cleanrules and I have recreated only the one rule that won't work. All of my other rules, which work fine, are gone. Every time I "run rules now" it works great, as expected. Then the messages pile up in my inbox and I have to manually run the rules again. I've removed my .SRS files and I can see the new ones have been generated.
Please help. I need my alert e-mails to be organized in to folders so I can read one category at a time.

ENVIRONMENT:
Office Home and Business 2013 Version: 15.0.4971.1002 OutLook connecting via MAPI to the local Exchange server.

CRITICAL PIECE OF INFORMATION I FORGOT:
The rule is for a shared mailbox added to my account. I have 4 inboxen each of which I am attempting to organize in to folders. This is the reason why it wasn't working. You can't make rules for shared mailboxen from OutLook. Silly me. TIL.

Comment: I understand you are frustrated. But, if you can't even include the details of the rule you are trying to run, how do you expect ANYBODY to help you?

Comment: Also what is your e-mail service and who manages it? Most rules run on the Exchange server so it's not an Outlook issue at all.

Comment: I added the details of the rule and that the Exchange server is hosted locally. I'm not sure how to make rules on the Exchange server. I believe they live in OutLook and only run when my OutLook is open.

Comment: Thank you. No, the rules run on the server unless they have to be client-side. The rule you listed is a server-side rule. It runs on Exchange. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Server-side-vs-client-only-rules-E1847992-8AA1-4158-8E24-AD043DECF1EB

Comment: I saw a quick comment on another forum about disabling this option: Outlook Options > Mail > Conversation Clean Up > "Don't move categorized messages."

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I just learned that you can't make rules for a shared account using OutLook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that you can't make mailbox rules for shared mailboxen using Outlook. The workaround is to use Outlook Web Access (OWA) to make the server-side rule for that mailbox. Thanks to @Appleoddity for the hint that the rule is server-side. That lead me to this answer.

Here is the post that helped me:
https://faq.icto.umac.mo/how-do-i-create-mail-rules-on-a-shared-mailbox/

Once logged in to OWA you can switch to any mailbox which the Exchange admin has given you permissions on by clicking your name in the upper right corner. Then you can make your rules by clicking Options, right below, also in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. That didn't even cross my mind.